# Laravel: when executing a guzzle POST and receiving a 302 Response(expected) how to proceed

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, guzzle

The way this works is that I first do a guzzle POST request with certain data and I receive a Guzzle 302 Response object. That's expected..I should go to a external page then.

But when following the link to the external page like so:
`\Redirect::away($response->getHeader('Location')[0]);`

I get a session expired page(on the external page).

Is there more to it when following the redirect url from the Guzzle 302 response object?

Do I have to include more data?

This is the full 302 Response object:

```
Response {#4354 ▼
  -reasonPhrase: "Found"
  -statusCode: 302
  -headers: array:8 [▼
    "Date" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "Fri, 20 Oct 2023 11:09:22 GMT"
    ]
    "Strict-Transport-Security" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
    ]
    "X-XSS-Protection" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "1; mode=block"
    ]
    "X-Content-Type-Options" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "nosniff"
    ]
    "Set-Cookie" => array:3 [▼
      0 => "someId=someValue; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None"
      1 => "someId=someValue; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None"
      2 => "someId=someValue; Path=/; Secure; HTTPOnly"
    ]
    "Location" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "https://external-url.com"
    ]
    "Content-Length" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "0"
    ]
    "Content-Security-Policy" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "default-src https: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src https://*.gstatic.com 'self' data:; object-src 'none'"
    ]
  ]
  -headerNames: array:8 [▼
    "date" => "Date"
    "strict-transport-security" => "Strict-Transport-Security"
    "x-xss-protection" => "X-XSS-Protection"
    "x-content-type-options" => "X-Content-Type-Options"
    "set-cookie" => "Set-Cookie"
    "location" => "Location"
    "content-length" => "Content-Length"
    "content-security-policy" => "Content-Security-Policy"
  ]
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: Stream {#4371 ▼
    -stream: stream resource @19 ▼
      wrapper_type: "PHP"
      stream_type: "TEMP"
      mode: "w+b"
      unread_bytes: 0
      seekable: true
      uri: "php://temp"
      options: []
    }
    -size: null
    -seekable: true
    -readable: true
    -writable: true
    -uri: "php://temp"
    -customMetadata: []
  }
}
```

I first did this by submitting via HTML form which does POST the form and redirects to the external page just fine.
Now I want to do this via guzzle POST and without a HTML form submit in between.

Comment: If this is a cookie-based session, then this of course CAN NOT work. The client making the first request, is your server. The client that you are redirecting, so that it will make that second request, is your site visitor's browser. Your server received the cookie that holds the session ID - and your site visitor's browser is the one that would need to send this cookie value back with the second request. But you can not "inject" cookies for a different domain into the user's browser.

Comment: ah so it is not possible because the cookies are from a different domain. So only option would be to use the HTML form to do the POST request and then the browser will follow/handle the redirect. Hmmm..I really wanted to eliminate the need of a HTML form submit in between..Thanks for your info!